# Problem with Unicode in C++ exe (MSVC++2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode, wchar-t

I have a strange problem which I don't know where it came from. I might have changed some settings in the MSVC++2010 project but it all looks good to me.

I'm currently experimenting with the VSHADOW.EXE 3.0 tool included with Windows SDK 6.1. This is a sort of backup program written in C++ and the strings in it are composed of `wchar_t`s. Now, my arguments (such as `-q`) which I pass to the program always result in strings of japanese symbols in the program. This occurs if I start the program normally via cmd, but also if I specify commandline arguments in the Visual Studio project settings and start the debugger.

Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is your program Unicode throughout or do you have a mix? How are you converting between Unicode and MBCS? Are you using `main()` or `_tmain()` or `wmain()`, i.e. what type are you receiving the arguments as?

Comment: @Rup: Oh. I know what I changed. I didn't know what `wmain` did, so I just changed it to `main`, LOL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post your 'EDIT' as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I changed `wmain` to `main` for a test and forgot to change it back.